# getting value of method parameters while the program is running

Tags: java, profiling

I need to figure out how to see the values of a java method while the program is running.
I can't change the code which is running, and I don't want to block the running of the code (so using debug mode in eclipse is off the table).
I just want to tell a profiler, or something similar, to print all the parameters a specific method receives each time it is called.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thank :)

Comment: Are you talking about the data types, the name of the arguements or both that you want returned?

Comment: The values of those arguements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you case you should use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). Wrap your method with custom code and log all its invocations. In one project we used AspectJ to log method execution time for profiling purposes.

Comment: If I am correct, this will require me to recompile the code, I can not do that.

Comment: No it will not. If you cant add annotations to your classes you can use xml configuration. Explore AOP better http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).
Suppose you have a class with a method that you want analize, like this:

```
    public class Example {

      public void doSomething(parameters) {
         doSomething;
      }
    }
```

You can extend this class and add behavior for profiling the method.
So you can do this:

```
    public class FilePrinterExample extends Example{

      @Override
      public void doSomething(parameters) {
          for each parameters do
              //print on file or what you want
          super.doSomething(parameters);
      }
    }
```

I use some pseudocode, and hope I was clear.

Answer (score 1):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) can do that. Create a method trigger for the desired methods and add a "Print method invocation action" to it:

[image]

If you need greater flexibility, [this screencast](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2011/09/using-run-interceptor-script-trigger.html) shows how to use the "Run interceptor script" in order to extract internal state from a running application.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it. does it have a trial period or a demo?

Comment: Yes, it comes with a 10 day trial which is fully functional, you can just download it from the web site.